# C# count and list pairs of dict of another method

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have the below code, and I need to find how many, and all pairs, of dictionary, which however belongs in another namespace's method:

```
using sys = System;
using gen = System.Collections.Generic;

namespace xtra
{
    class TestClass
    {
        public void Sing()
        {
            gen::Dictionary<string, int> dict = new gen::Dictionary<string, int>()
            {
                ["A"] = 1,
                ["B"] = 2,
                ["C"] = 3

            };
        }
    }
}



namespace ConsoleApp99
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            xtra.TestClass Joe = new xtra.TestClass();
            Joe.Sing();
            foreach (string name in Joe.Keys)  //error!
                sys.Console.WriteLine($"{name} {dict[name]}"); //error!
        }
    }
}
```

So, the method Sing creates and populates a dictionary, but, upon instantiation in another namespace (in Main), I can create it, but, how do I count pairs and print their values?? I do understand that Joe is a method that makes the dictionary, but I have no clue to reference Joe's dictionary..

Comment: You should return reference to your dictionary in Sing method or pass dictionary reference in property (field) of class TestClass.

Comment: `sys`, `gen`? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dict` property access modifier must be `public` in order to access him from another class.
Another approach is to expose only the `dict` property by encapsulating him and make `Sing()` method `private`.

```
class TestClass
{
    private Dictionary<string, int> _dict;
    public Dictionary<string, int> dict
    {
        get
        {
            if (_dict == null)
            {
                Sing();
            }
            return _dict;
        }
        set { _dict = value; }
    }

    private void Sing()
    {
        _dict = new Dictionary<string, int>()
        {
            ["A"] = 1,
            ["B"] = 2,
            ["C"] = 3
        };
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        xtra.TestClass Joe = new xtra.TestClass();
        foreach (string name in Joe.dict.Keys)
            sys.Console.WriteLine($"{name} {Joe.dict[name]}");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, understood. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define this dictionary as public property inside of `TestClass` in order to have access to it from different class/namespace:

```
namespace xtra
{
    class TestClass
    {
        public Dictionary<string, int> Dict { get; set; }

        public void Sing()
        {
            Dict = new Dictionary<string, int>()
            {
                ["A"] = 1,
                ["B"] = 2,
                ["C"] = 3

            };
        }
    }
}

namespace ConsoleApp99
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            xtra.TestClass Joe = new xtra.TestClass();
            Joe.Sing();
            foreach (string name in Joe.Dict.Keys)  //error!
                sys.Console.WriteLine($"{name} {Joe.Dict[name]}"); //error!
        }
    }
}
```